# phpspreadsheet setFormatCode performance issue

Tags: excel, phpspreadsheet

We detected cases where somewhat bigger exports became very slow, so we tried to analyse the issue. We are talking about an export of - just as an example - roughly 600 columns by 6000 rows.

Side note: We work with CakePHP and have an ExportHelper which internally uses a Spreadsheet instance and binds the active worksheet to an internal property for quicker reference. There is a function for adding a whole row, but within the function, each cell and its styles are added individually.

In the given case, we do not add formulas or visual styling in a sense of colors, borders, font styling etc. No combined cells either.

But we need to apply number formats to the cells of some columns. If we comment out the code applying the style, e.g.

```
$this->_xlsWorksheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($c, $r)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00);
```

...then the export takes only seconds. But if we leave the code in, the export either takes minutes, or it even crashes due to memory problems. Switching on caching did not seem to help.

So I am wondering: Is there anything that can be done to speed up these cell formatting related calls? Should we maybe first write all the cell contents, and only at the end apply the style to the complete column, meaning: a cell range from the second to the last row (excluding the first row which contains a header), instead of applying the style to the cells with individual calls?

Answer (score 0):

If your solution works fine without formatting, you can modify the data before creating the XML file.

If you need to export that much data, perhaps a CSV file is the best option. Anyway, MS Excel is going to crash with such a large file. Ha ha.

Comment: We offer an alternative CSV export in our software, that is a viable option. Opening such a CSV then in Excel works fine, so I do not think that the size itself (in regards to the product of columns and rows) is a problem.
Formatting is needed as numeric values are otherwise treated as strings, leading to all kinds of disadvantages (no sums of selected cell range in footer etc.)